# Exporting custom UTI results in UIDocumentInteractionController error 513 "Unable to link file"

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, info.plist, uidocumentinteraction

I have an application that currently accepts incoming files via UIDocumentInteractionController file types, but I'd also like to export a custom UTI to allow other applications to share *only* to my app if they  prefer (as opposed to all apps that support incoming files of the same type). Basically I am trying to mimic what Instagram does (http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/).

While setting the UTI on the `UIDocumentInteractionController` *does* result in only my application being shown to the user, it also results in the following error. The error does not occur if the `UIDocumentInteractionController` UTI property is not set:

```
2013-07-15 10:56:02.476 Example[1117:907] Unable to link file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/55C3F66E-725D-487C-B538-30139C685101/Example.app/photo.png 
to file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/55C3F66E-725D-487C-B538-30139C685101/tmp/8C6C5225-6582-406C-83CD-BC5A92B91D09/photo.iracephoto. 
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)
```

Here is the UTI export in my Info.plist file:

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>me.irace.photo</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>iracephoto</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is trying to share a photo from the resource bundle. Copying it to the Documents folder gets rid of the error message.